# function in main program OK, undefined references otherwise

Tags: c++, c++11, linker, header-files, undefined-reference

I have a function, that when defined in the main file of my program, works as I wish, and produces a lot of undefined references, when defined in a header file.

This header file exists:

```
#include "Domain.h"
#include "Character.h"

class Item {
    public:
        Character input;
        Item(Character c2);
};
Item pistol(int which, float strength);
```

The function that makes problems is `pistol`. It looks like

```
Item pistol(int which, float strength) {
    Interval i = Interval(0, 1);
    Domain d = Domain(i);
    Character c = Character({d}, {1});
    return Item(c);
}
```

When I try to link the code with my main program, all calls that refer to object in `Domain.h` and `Character.h` are `undefined references`, that means I get linking time errors like:

```
undefined reference to `Character::show()'
...
undefined reference to `Interval::Interval(float, float)'
...
```

these errors are at places in the code, which are not inside the `pistol` function.

When I move this function to my main program, everything works as expected:

```
#include "Domain.h"
#include "Character.h"
#include "Item.h"

Item pistol(int which, float strength) {
    // definition, see above
}

int main() {
    Item w2 = pistol(2, 0.5);
    return 0;
}
```

What is the problem with that function being in `Item.h`/`Item.cxx`?
What do I need to do to put it their?

Comment: you right, I'm very unexperienced in doing multi file c++, and just found out, how to do that in cmake

Comment: Cool!! You shortened your question! +1 for doing this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`undefined reference` is a **linking stage** error.

You most probably missed to link with a compilation unit, missed to recompile a dependent compilation unit, or tried to have a template class/function definition not seen by the compiler from **all** your compilation units using it!

Comment: it was a missing dependency in a compilation unit. Adding `target_link_libraries` in `cmake` helped

Comment: @spiehr Sorry I can't upvote your question (in return of accepting), since as it stands it's really _"TL;DR;"_ prone ... Try for some improvement (without obfuscating or destroying the original question plase)

Comment: @spiehr _' what does TL;DR stands for?'_ Look here for explanation: [TL;DR;](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tl%3Bdr) `Too Long; Didn't Read;` literally ...

Comment: @spiehr I'd like to clarify, that `TL;DR;` isn't meant to be kind of disrespect on your efforts to write this question up, or on the topic being asked for! It's just, that I had a lucky shot, to solve your problems, by just spotting the _real problem_ from your explanations and code samples when "skimming" these.